# Seqelize error when trying to run migrations on Heroku

Tags: heroku, database-migration, sequelize.js

So I've triple checked my config.json to make sure that all of the keys are aligned with the heroku database:

```
"production": {
  "name": "NAME",
  "user": "USER",
  "port": "5432",
  "pass": "PASSWORD",
  "host": "HOST",
  "dialect": "postgres"
}
```

I know these values are working because I can access the db with pgcommander.  I then do the following steps:

`heroku config:set NODE_ENV='production' --app APP_NAME`

`heroku run node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate`

but always end up with the following error after the migration fails:

```
[00:27:42] Finished 'db:migrate' after 88 ms
Unable to connect to database: Error: SequelizeConnectionError: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
```

A google search for the error returns a surprisingly small amount of relevant results.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this by changing my `config.json` and using a different order of heroku commands:

First I had to promote the heroku db: [instructions for promoting db](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#establish-primary-db) then change my

`config.json`

to the following:

```
"production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL"
}
```

Then run the following commands in terminal:

`heroku run bash`

now inside heroku bash:

`sequelize db:migrate`

I'm still not sure why specifying each key of the db url in config.json was giving me an error as they should be exactly the same.